# PeoplePicker not find users in FBA using multiple domains

Tags: 2007, sharepoint-enterprise, active-directory, forms-authentication

I'm facing a problem with my forms authentication that has consumed me some good hours.

My forms authentication points to 2 providers. Both are AD using a ldap connection to diferent domains.

I have the following provider configuration on my web.config

```
<membership defaultProvider="AD">
  <providers>
    <add name="AD" type="System.Web.Security.ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider, System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" connectionStringName="ADService" connectionUsername="domain1\Admin" connectionPassword="Password" connectionProtection="None" attributeMapUsername="sAMAccountName" enableSearchMethods="true" />
    <add name="AD2" type="System.Web.Security.ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider, System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" connectionStringName="ADTeste" connectionUsername="domain2\Admin" connectionPassword="Password123" connectionProtection="None" attributeMapUsername="sAMAccountName" enableSearchMethods="true" />
  </providers>
</membership>
```

PeoplePicker is unable to find users from the second connection. I already added the  provider, but still have the problem. Does anyone have an idea what i'm missing ?

Here follows my  on web.config

```
<PeoplePickerWildcards>
  <clear />      
  <add key="AD" value="%" />
  <add key="AD2" value="%" />
</PeoplePickerWildcards>
```

Comment: Do you have both of your connection strings in place?

Comment: My connection strings can be found below the </SharePoint> tag. They were tested by my custom login page, which uses the connection string to autenticate the users
Follow the cs: <connectionStrings> <add name="ADService" connectionString="LDAP://Domain1.org.br/DC=Domain1,DC=org,DC=br" /> <add name="ADTESTE" connectionString="LDAP://Domain2.org.br/DC=Domain2,DC=org,DC=br" /> </connectionStrings>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just solved the problem.

My SharePoint farm is installed on domain which provider AD points to. I did the following steps to solve it:

1º Change the default provider in the original web application to AD2.

2º On the extended web app, I changed the default provider to AD.

Now, peoplepicker is able to find the users from both domains.

Thank you for all the comments

Answer (score 0):

You would need to add that connection string in 3 places on your farm (beware of multiple WFE as these manual changes require manual input in all WFE!) - Central Administration, Web Services and your target Web Application for this to work properly!

Comment: To be a tad more precise: web.config of your web application, web.config of your central administration site and web.config of your STS service. I also assume you're using claims based authentication? Please add your connectionstring config as well, I notice your config says "ADTeste" as name, which seems weird.

Comment: I'm using moss 2007. 
I forgot to add the connection strings on my SSP. Tried to add it on ssp wb.config, but still not working.

The connection strings:

    <connectionStrings>
    <add name="ADService" connectionString="LDAP://Domain1.org.br/DC=Domain1,DC=org,DC=br" />
    <add name="ADTESTE" connectionString="LDAP://Domain2.org.br/DC=Domain2,DC=org,DC=br" />
    </connectionStrings>

Comment: ahh...you should have mentioned that as equation changes, but still you need to keep your web.config on CA and Web-App at least!

Comment: I did it, still not working. I can log on in my site with a user from Domain2, but it has no permission, since i'm unable give permissions using peoplepicker.

Comment: Make sure the case of your connection string name is the same. ADTESTE != ADTeste

Comment: Checked it, it is correct on my env.

Answer (score 0):

For LDAP providers, the search character is "*", not "%".  Is there a reason you're not using Microsoft.Office.Server.Security.LdapMembershipProvider?  Here is the way the web.configs are supposed to be configured: [http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc197251(v=office.12).aspx](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc197251%28v=office.12%29.aspx).

Comment: I've followed this post http://www.devx.com/enterprise/Article/35068 to configure my FBA. I will change the web.config as you mentioned and check for differences.

Comment: I changed the web.config file using the site you mentioned. I still have the same problem, peoplepicker can find users from domain1 but not domain2. Also, my custom login page cannot authenticate more the users from both domains.
Dont i have to inform web.config the connection string user and password for domain?